# Unable to download files from s3 because a junk string is appended to key name

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to download all the files and folders from a specific folder in S3 bucket and download in a specific local folder. When I try to download, I get the exception:

> No such file or directory

I tried different snippets of codes to perform the same task but could not solve the issue. Here is the code snippet:

```
def download(self):
    s3_bucket = self.resource.Bucket(self.bucket)
    for s3_object in s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=self.folder):
        local_path = os.path.join(self.local_path, s3_object.key)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(local_path)):
            os.makedirs(local_path)

        key = str(s3_object.key)
        if not key.endswith('/'):
            logging.info("Downloading {}".format(key))
            s3_bucket.download_file(s3_object.key, key)

    return json.dumps({"msg": "data is downloaded"})
```

But It gives me the error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'temp/abc/metrics_data.csv.CDBdfD3f'

The actual key of the file is temp/abc/metrics_data.csv but I don't know from where ".CDBdfD3f" is appended. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late but I've had the same issue and the problem is the directory you are writing your file to does not exist. I had a case sensitivity problem and once I've put the correct path everything worked as expected.